# creating a file in c every 60 ms to save bitmap image

Tags: c

I get image data(752x480pixels) from server (camera sensor) in raw rgb 24bits format every 60 ms. I succesfully tried to open a file with fopen("imageinfo.txt","w+").

What happens is the image raw data is getting written over and over in the same file and at the end of my simulation in server, what i have is only one file which has the raw data that came in the last 60th ms.

How do i create a new file for every 60ms and save the image data which i have in variable" char img " received using winsock recv function.

The simulation time is not constant. For example, the simulation would go on for 10 mins, or 20 mins, or 30 mins, but i want a new file to be created every 60 ms.

```
              if (sscanf(VDScfg.sbuf, "*VDS %d %s %f %dx%d %d", &Channel,ImgType,                            &SimTime, &ImgWidth, &ImgHeight, &ImgLen) == 6) 
               {
                   if (ImgLen > 0) {
                      if (strcmp(ImgType, "rgb") == 0) {
                        char *img = (char *)malloc(ImgLen);
                            for (len=0; len<ImgLen; len+=res) {
                               if ((res=recv(VDScfg.sock, img+len, ImgLen-len, VDScfg.RecvFlags)) < 0) {
                                 printf ("VDS: Socket Reading Failure\n");
                                   break;
                                    }
            }
            if (len == ImgLen) {
                FILE *fp; 
                fp=fopen("imageinfo.txt","w+");
                fprintf(fp,"%s",img);
                fclose(fp);
                MinDepthPixel = 0;

                nPixel = ImgLen/sizeof(float);
                f_img = (float *)img;

                for (Pixel = 0; Pixel < nPixel; Pixel++) {
                    if(f_img[Pixel] < f_img[MinDepthPixel])
                        MinDepthPixel = Pixel;
                }
                VDSIF.MinDepth = f_img[MinDepthPixel];

                if (VDScfg.Verbose) {
                    /* Print general image information */
                    printf ("> %s\n", VDScfg.sbuf);

                    printf (" Minimal distance: %6.3f m\n Pixel position: x = %u, y = %u\n\n",VDSIF.MinDepth, MinDepthPixel%ImgWidth, MinDepthPixel/ImgWidth);
                }
                }
            free (img);
        }
    }if (ImgLen > 0) {
             `if (strcmp(ImgType, "rgb") == 0) {
              char *img = (char *)malloc(ImgLen);
              for (len=0; len<ImgLen; len+=res) {
                if ((res=recv(VDScfg.sock, img+len, ImgLen-len, VDScfg.RecvFlags)) < 0)
                 {                                        
                    printf("VDS: Socket Reading Failure\n");
                    break;
                }
              }
              if (len == ImgLen) {
                FILE *fp; 
                fp=fopen("imageinfo.txt","w+");
                fprintf(fp,"%s",img);
                  }
            }
```

Comment: Please show your code. If you are always writing to "imageinfo.txt", of course you will have only this file.

Comment: Please edit the original question and put your code there. You can't post it all as a comment, and it is unreadable.

Comment: @davir : i am a newbie here, so didnt know exactly how to add a code ..kindly see the original question along with the code. thanks

Comment: That's ok. The code you just posted is in a loop, I assume? Please show a little more. The whole loop should suffice.

Comment: @davir : yeah  please check now, after creating the file, i do some image processing.but the main focus is creating a file every time the control gets into if len==Imglen. Perhaps this happens every 60 ms as the server is configured to send image data at that rate.

Comment: Ok, this last comment is exactly what I wanted. Now you have a better question and we can start working on answers.

Comment: Please edit your code, you probably accidently duplicated some of your code. And your code is really difficult to read. May be you want to **append** the data to the imageinfo.txt file, then you must fopen it with "a+" and not "w+". It's not really clear want you actually want.

Comment: @MichaelWalz : please look at the code now. I dont want to append the raw data in a single file. I want to create a new file every time the control comes into the loop and checks if len==Imglen

Comment: Why do you have `fp=fopen("imageinfo.txt","w+");`in two different places ? And If you want to create different files, then you have... to create files with a different name each time, See davir's answer for getting an idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new files, with different filenames. If you are always opening the same file name, of course you will always write to the same file.

The following simple code example will create and write "hi" to 10 different files: imginfo0.txt - imginfo9.txt. I am sure you can adapt this to your own needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char filename[32];

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char img[3];
    strcpy(img, "hi");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sprintf(filename, "imageinfo%d.txt", i);
        fp=fopen(filename,"w+");
        fprintf(fp, "%s", img);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Remember to fclose() your files when you are done with them!